# Barlegend with a different z span for ListDensityPlot

Tags: plotting, legending

I would like to rescale the colors in a plot and to do this in the same way for the color bar. (So this enables me to have the color bar span a (z) range larger than than the data itself.)

I got this running for Plot3D:

```
Plot3D[Sin[x^2 + y], {x, 0, Pi}, {y, 0, Pi}, 
  ColorFunctionScaling -> False, 
  ColorFunction -> (ColorData["SolarColors", Rescale[#3, {0, 1}, {0, 1}]] &), 
  PlotLegends -> BarLegend[{"SolarColors", {0, 1}}, 10]]
```

How can I accomplish the same for `ListDensityPlot`? A simple copy and past doesn't do the job; I get an error w.r.t. the used slot number (#3) in the code above. Which slot should be used for this purpose in `ListDensityPlot`?

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1):

```
DensityPlot[Sin[x^2 + y], {x, 0, Pi}, {y, 0, Pi}, 
 ColorFunction -> (ColorData["TemperatureMap", Rescale[#, {0, 2}, {0, 1}]] &), 
 PlotLegends -> BarLegend[{"TemperatureMap", {0, 2}}, 10]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Answer (score 0):

I modified the answer by belisarius for listdensityplot and moreover I rescaled the barlegend such that the desired result was obtained:

All the data outside the desired range gets the same "bottom" color.

```
 data = Table[Sin[u + v^2], {u, 0, 3, .05}, {v, 0, 3, .05}];
 zrange = {.5, 1.0}

 ListDensityPlot[data, 
 ColorFunction -> ColorData[{"SolarColors", zrange}], 
PlotLegends -> 
 BarLegend[{(ColorData["SolarColors", Rescale[#, zrange, {0, 1}]] &),
 zrange}]]
```

[image]

The documentation of Mathematica needs an update for this.